# Spatial indexing in Strabon

Tags: geospatial, sparql, semantic-web, geo, linked-data

I recently installed several triple stores to test the performance of them regarding geospatial queries (when possible). One of those triple stores is [Strabon](http://strabon.di.uoa.gr). In the other triple stores it was necessary to do an index or specific a spatial index to optimize query times.

However I couldn't find anything regarding Strabon and indexing of the data. Does anyone know if it's possible and how it's done?

Answer (score 2):

Does the [User Guide](http://strabon.di.uoa.gr/node/20) not cover this?

In the section titled **Creating a spatially enabled database** it says the following:

> Spatially-enabled databases permit the use of spatial function calls.
>   MonetDB creates spatially-enabled databases by default if you have
>   enabled the geom module. More information on how to create a
>   spatially-enabled database in PostGIS  can be found here:
>   http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/.

Followed by a bunch of steps you need to run to enable this

Comment: You are right that PostGIS installation is covered in the Strabon user guide. However in other software (like Virtuoso or Owlim) you will have to run a seperate command to create a spatial index. In Parliament for example there is a button/link in the administrator interface which does the same thing.

Comment: The phrasing appears in the quote I reproduced appears to imply that configuring PostGIS appropriately should be sufficient and that spatial indexing is automatic once this is done

Comment: I can see what you are getting at. I also contacted the developer with the same question (and a patch) and I hope he will reply to me shortly. Thanks for your input though.